# What is the reason of a referenceError when trying to use a function from cdn script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, import, redux

I can't use npm, not familiar with the details, currently trying to learn 'redux'. What can be the problem here?

When executing this code, I'm getting a "Uncaught ReferenceError: createStore is not defined
    at ind.js:5"

Below you can see the code snippet that I have a problem with:

```
function playlist(state=[]){
return state;
}

const store = createStore(playlist);

console.log(store.getState());
```

And I have this script tag in HTML file's head tag:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.0/redux.min.js"></script>
```

And the js file's script tag in body's end:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./ind.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is the code snippet placed in the body or head?

Comment: In the head, I've written that above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm sorry my previous answer was unhelpful! As it says in the [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/store) you need to `import` the `createStore` function before you can use it. That is easily done in Node.js, but without it you need to use the ES6 module. Although support for it is supposedly growing, I've still had plenty of trouble with it. This should be supported in Chrome and Edge. To get this to work on Firefox below version 60, go to `about:config` and change `dom.moduleScripts.enabled` to `true`.

Change your script tag to this:

`<script type="module" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.0/redux.min.js"></script>`

and add this as the first line of your code: `import { createStore } from 'redux'`

Comment: Sir, do you even read the question's description? I've already done that.

Comment: Yes. When I asked about the code snippet, I was referring to the one you "had trouble with." You said that was in the <head> as well, so I suggested to move it to the <body>.

Comment: Ok, I edited the description with more details. The main js file is in the <body> :)